# JPA cascade persist - many to one

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have a many to one relationship and I am trying to persist a child entity.

```
public class Office
{
public int id;
public int grades;
@OneToMany
public set<Employee> employees;
}

public class Employee{
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GeneratedValue.identity)
public int empid;
@ManyToOne(cascade=cascadeType.ALL)
public Office office;
}
```

Office Id is already present in the database. But employee is not.
Now if i am adding an employee and his grades must go into the office database.

When i do the following operation,grades are not getting saved

```
Office office = new Office();
office.setId(23);
office.setGrades(5);
employee.setOffice(office);
em.persist(employee);
```

How to save grades into the office table in a single operation

Answer (score 18):

First, fix your mapping.

The association is bidirectional, and one of the side (the one side) must be marked as the inverse of the other using the mappedBy attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "office")
public set<Employee> employees;
```

The employee is only one of the employees of the office. Do you really want to delete the entire office when you delete a single employee? If not, why do you put a `cascade=cascadeType.ALL` on the `@ManyToOne`? Those annotations have consequences. Don't use them without understanding them.

Now to really answer the question. If the office already exists in the database, you should not build a new one. Go fetch it from the database and update it:

```
Office office = em.find(Office.class, 23);
// office is now attached, and any change you make on the entity will be written to the database
office.setGrade(5);
```

Now you may also attach the office to the new employee. But since it's a bidirectional relationship, you should also initialize the other side of the association to keep the object graph coherent:

```
employee.setOffice(office);
office.addEmployee(employee);
em.persist(employee);
```

Comment: If I'd have to call em.persist(employee), what is the cascade good for?

Comment: The cascade is used to cascade operations. If you have a cascade of type persist on a.b, and you call persist on a, then persist will automatically be called on b as well. In the above you don't call any operation on office, so there's nothing to cascade.

Comment: Allright, I see now.
About the "mappedBy": it's optional. If you use it, hibernate will use a column for the mapping, if left out, it will use an additional table.
The table is kind of overkill, but I didn't like the circular dependencies. I think they could introduce memory leaks.

Comment: mappedBy is not optional in a bidirectional association. If you don't use it, you have two, unrelated, unidirectional associations.