# Avoid duplicates in JPA Many-to-One

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have asked a variation of this question previously for Hibernate.  However, I am now working with Eclipselink and it still troubles me.  It is very simple:

I need to persist an address object that includes a city name in a many-to-one relationship.  I would like to be able to persist the address and cascade save the city - but only if the city is unique.  From my understanding this is not supported directly by JPA?  Possible solutions include using the city name as the unique id in the city table and querying the city table for a specific city and then adding that object to the address prior to saving.  I have certainly seen several StackOverflow questions/answers that seem to suggest this is the approach ([JPA cascade persist - many to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049264/jpa-cascade-persist-many-to-one))

Am I missing something here?  Is there an alternative/better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution is to get the city from the database, create it if it doesn't exist, and set it to the address.

There's no way around that. The city name doesn't have to be the primary key, though. I would use an autogenerated, non-functional, surrogate key as the PK, and add a unique constraint on the name of the city. This would at least allow you to fix typos in city names without having to update the thousand addresses referencing them.